# How to get Python 3.5 and Anaconda 3.5 running on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ubuntu, anaconda

Anaconda for python 3.5 and python 2.7 seems to install just as a drop in folder inside my home folder on Ubuntu.  Is there an installed version of Anaconda for Ubuntu 16?  I'm not sure how to ask this but do I need python 3.5 that comes by default if I am also using Anaconda 3.5?

It seems like the best solution is docker these days.  I mean I understand virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper.  However, sometimes I try to indicate in my .bashrc that I want to use python 3.5 and yet I'll use the command mkvirtualenv and it will start installing the python 2.7 versions of python.

Should I choose either Anaconda or the version of python installed with my OS from python.org or is there an easy way to manage many different versions of Python?
Thanks,
Bruce

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution for Python 3.5 and Anaconda on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (with the bonus of OpenCV 3) was to install Anaconda, then deprecate to 3.5.   You have to be sure to update anaconda afterwards - that's the bit that got me at first.  The commands I gave were:

```
bash Anaconda3-4.3.1-Linux-x86_64.sh
conda install python=3.5
conda update anaconda
conda install -c menpo opencv3
```

This seems to work for me; tried it on a few other Ubuntu 16.04 machines as well, and it seemed to work well.

Answer (score 0):

Use anaconda version `Anaconda3-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh` from the anaconda installer archive.This comes with `python 3.5`. This worked for me.